# Browsing 64 bit mode web application on iis 6.0 SP2 throws 503 and stops app pool

Tags: asp.net, iis, 64-bit, iis-6

Found following error in event viewer:

The Module name ManagedEngineV4.0_64bit path C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\webengine4.dll returned an error from registration.  The data is the error.

Please help.

I have registered .net frameworks again and still get same error.

Comment: IIS 6 has died for years.

Comment: I know but in some old servers we are still supporting.